# Cloud Firestore - Access Field for Realtime Updates

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access a field labeled `vote_count` via Cloud Firestore realtime updates.

Below is my data structure:

[image]

Previously, under Firebase Realtime Database, I would .addValueEventListener() and drill down to the "answer." However, with Cloud Firestore, it is a bit more complex.

> ```
>     mStoreSelectedPollRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onEvent(final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
>             if (e != null){
>                 Log.v("LISTEN", "LISTEN_FAILED");
>                 return;
>             }
>             if (documentSnapshot != null){
>                 Log.v("Current Data", String.valueOf(documentSnapshot.getData()));
>                 mStoreSelectedPollRef.collection(ANSWERS_LABEL).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
>                         updatePollResultAnswersDynamically(task.getResult().size(), documentSnapshot);
>                     }
>                 });
>             } else {
>                 Log.v("Current Data", "Current Data Nulll");
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

Right now, I am adding a call to .get() within my Snapshot Listener, which seems to be inefficient. I was curious how I would access the:

1. Total number of answer Documents.
2. Each individual answer

Comment: I don't understand the code.  It looks like it's saying "every time a certain document changes, query all the documents in the answers collection, count them, then do something with the first document".  If you want to maintain a document count without having to pull an entire collection, there is a pattern for that.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: I essentially want to query the answers and get the size of the answers. Then i want to access the individual fields within each answer. In order to do this, it appears I need to have both .addSnapshotListener and .addOnCompleteListener(). Trying to figure out if there is a way to simplify

Comment: OK, I'm confused.  You have mStoreSelectedPollRef and you're essentially querying it twice, once for incremental changes, and again for size and content?

Comment: I guess I could add my .addSnapshotListener() to my answers node, but again I am not sure if the DocumentSnapshot it returns will give me the data I need

Comment: I don't think you need a snapshot listener at all.  Just query the entire collection once with get(), iterate the documents in it, and do what you want with each of them.

Comment: .get() is not for realtime updates, as far as I can tell https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: Querying the entire collection every time one thing in it changes is neither typical nor efficient. But if that's what you need, then so be it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get CollectionReference count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count)

Answer (score 0):

Given this snippet:

```
mStoreSelectedPollRef.collection(ANSWERS_LABEL).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        updatePollResultAnswersDynamically(task.getResult().size(), documentSnapshot);
    }
});
```

You can get the total number of answer documents with:

```
task.getResult().size()
```

Since you already have this code, I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you're asking if there is a way to get the count without getting the documents, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555026

To access the individual answer documents, you loop over the query snapshot:

```
for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have .addSnapshotListener() and .addOnCompleteListener(). It seems a bit redundant, but the QuerySnapshot appears to offer more data than a DocumentSnapshot. Just wondering if this approach is conventional or if I am creating unnecessary code

Comment: You call `addSnapshotListener` on the `QcU...` document, you call `get()` on its `answers` collection. If both are needed that is indeed the right way to load them.

Comment: Got it - essentially, I am trying to use realtime updates. The .addSnapshotListener() does not have the .size() method which is why I am essentially nesting another .get() method. My understanding is realtime updates are activated only under .addSnapshotListener()

Comment: `addSnapshotListener` gets a single snapshot. Its size would always be `1`. Keep in mind: when you load a document, its nested collections are not automatically loaded.

Comment: Got it, so in other words, there is no issue calling .get() afterward. I am trying to compare it to the realtime database, where you can add the listener, drill down into the nodes of that listener, .getChildrenCount(), and others. It doesn't mirror it completely when I was first trying to replicate every method

Comment: In this case the difference is quite intentional: reads in Firestore are shallow, they don't read subcollections. If you want all data in one read, consider if the answers shouldn't actually be nested/sub-fields in the same document (instead of a subcollection).

Comment: Got it - so it may be a hint that I should restructure the data and maybe even create a separate answers node