# Maintain a summery field in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my app, I have events with items.
Each item related to a user and has a price.

I also had the sum of items per user, and a global sum(and average).

Right now, those sums are calculating in firebase functions, and calculate from "scratch" each time.
The reason is to avoid race condition when 2 items will be added at the same time and read the same current value.

The problem - it works too slow..

What is the "proper" way to implement this?
Is there a way to assure no race conditions?

I though to do a double work.
In client side, add/reduce the value of the specific item to the sums/avg, and also calculate from scratch in the "server" to avoing any issues. 
Is that a good way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get CollectionReference count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see a proper way to implement this.

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, but it seems to answer. I will need to use transaction from client side.