# Firestore order a collection based on likes

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to order my `ListView` of posts based on the likes (the most liked post must be displayed above)?

[image: How my Firebase database looks like]

I already know how I can order it based on timestamp. But as you can see the likes is a collection in Posts.

Timestamp code:

```
Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already know how to order based on timestamp, then you should do in the same way to order by likes. So to solve this, you need to add a new property under each post named `likes` and use the following line of code to query:

```
Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").orderBy("likes", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(3);
```

To update a the `likes` property, I recomment you using [Firestore Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

You can [count the number of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count/48540276) within a collection but in your case, the best option is to add a new property, as explained above.

Comment: Yes, it could. You can add a listener to get the number of likes and write it under the corresponding post. But il will be harder to maintain. In my solution, there a single property that will be updated and that's it. It's up to you which solution you choose.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answers. I understand and want to use the transactions method but I don't really know the right way to implement it in my file. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Yes, sure. First, I recommend checking out the documentation and trying it. If you get stuck during a specific step, show what you've tried and in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Also see the Firestore documentation page on maintaining counters: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank!