# How to get a count of the number of documents and the id's of these, in a collection with Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, how can I get the total number of documents and the id's of these in a collection?

For instance if I have

```
/Usuarios
    /Cliente
        /JORGE
            /456789
                /filtros
                      /status
                          /activo
                          /inactivo
```

My code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Task<QuerySnapshot> docRef = db.collection("Usuarios").document("Cliente").collection("JORGE").document("filtros").collection("status").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            int contador = 0;
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
                                contador++;
                            }

                            int cantPS = contador;
}
```

I want to query how many people I have and get: 2 and the id's: activo, inactivo.

Comment: Check also **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count/48540276)** out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the number of documents returned by a query, use [`QuerySnapshot.size()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#size()).

To get the list of documents returned by a query, use [`QuerySnapshot.getDocuments()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#getDocuments()).

To show the key of a document use [`DocumentSnapshot.getId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getId()).

So in total:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
        int count = querySnapshot.size();
        System.out.println(count);
        for (DocumentSnapshot document: querySnapshot.getDocuments()) {
            System.out.println(document.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help!. But this returns me 0 in the app. What I am doing is creating buttons dynamically with the amount of document that has a certain collection, and when applying the function provided by Firestore the "CollectionRefence", it has to be changed to: Task <QuerySnapshot> because if all the code of the function is wrong

Comment: When you run this code, should log the document, followed by each individual document ID. If it logs 0, there are no documents in the collection.

Comment: You're right, my friend, there were still fields to be able to recognize them. It's something that will stay with me, I'm just starting in the world of firebase. Thank you very much for your help.