# Firestore - Custom objects for nested collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The question may sound weird. I have the following custom `Object` that I named `ItemUser`:

```
private UserInfo user_info;
private List<UserAchievement> user_achievements;
```

Both fields have getters and setters. My Firestore's database looks like this:

[image]

I would like to get the `List` size instead of re-calling the database and getting the size of the collection from a separated call that would consume much resources and take a lot of time (3-4s).

Firstly I'm getting the data using this:

```
mDB.collection("COLLECTION_NAME").document("USER_ID").get()
```

Inside the `onCompletedListener` I'm getting the custom object as the following:

```
ItemUser mUser = task.getResult().toObject(ItemUser.class);
```

Now, when I'm trying to get the size of the `user_achievements`, a `NullPointerException` popups saying I can't get the size of a null reference.

Therefore the `user_achievements` is null. I think the way I'm defining `user_achievements` in my custom Object is the reason for this exception.

The question is: How could this be possible done without recalling the database to count only the size?

I have the main custom Object `ItemUser` and its children are 'healthy' except `user_achievements` because of the way it's defined - `List<UserAchievement>`.

So, any suggestions to overpass this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could this be possible done without recalling the database to count only the size?

No, because Cloud Firestore is a real-time database and items can be added or deleted, so to get the size of a list you need to query the database and use a `get()` call.

If you want to count the number of documents beneath a collection (which can be added to a list), please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count/48540276)** in which I have explained that `task.getResult().size()` can help you solve the problem.

**Edit:**

```
mDB.collection("COLLECTION_NAME").document("USER_ID").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int size = task.getResult().size();
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(size));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I should state that I'm using `get()` on a document, which means I'll have `OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>` rather than `QuerySnapshot`. Therefore `size()` isn't available as a method.

Comment: Why are you using `OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>` and not `OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>`?

Comment: Because I'm listening on the document in the first example `mDB.collection("COLLECTION_NAME").document("USER_ID").get()`. Using `QuerySnapshot` shows a `Couldn't resolve` error for mistype of the parameter.

Comment: You shoul use the code as in my updated answer. Don't also forget to add the corresponding dependencies.