# How getChildrenCount() works in the background?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my database I have lets say more than 5000 users, now if I use `getChildrenCount()` in the main parent node to get how many people do I have

I know that getChildrenCount returns a long with the quantity of children inside a parent but, how this affects performance ?

Months ago I made an app to manage users more efficient than doing it from the web console, since the page became static and the users growth.

Now, I want to know if every time I request the quantity of users the app is looping through the 5000+ users and count it for each one, so I'm wasting read resources.

My questions:

Does `getChildrenCount()` stores somewhere the latest retrieved number of my users ?
Does `getChildrenCount()` executes each time I run my app to count with += in each child ?

I think the best practice of doing this is runing getChildrenCount one time and then store those users in one node lets say `userQuantity = 5000` and then just add 1 to that node each time a new user comes in (with transactions), so in my app manager I just query a single node obtaining the quantity and it's more efficient than looping through all the parent node again to get the users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using DataSnapshot's `getChildrenCount()` method, it doesn't mean that you are looping through the entire `DataSnapshot` object. Instead, if you are using DataSnapshot's `getChildren()` method you are precisely doing that. Let's take an example, let's say you have a node named `users` which holds as you say, over 5000 users.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long numberOfUsers = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); // Count the number of users

        //This is called iteration
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // Get user object on every iteration
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Because every node in a Firebase database is a `Map`, [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) can also be called a `Map`.

> A DataSnapshot instance contains data from a Firebase Database location. Any time you read Database data, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot.

So if you want to cast a `DataSnapshot` object to a `Map`, the following line of code will work perfectly fine:

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot;
```

So calling `getChildrenCount()` on a `DataSnapshot` object is like calling `size()` method on a `Map`, which internally counts the number of objects it contains.

> I'm wasting read resources

This is available in case of the new Cloud Firestore database, where you are charged according to the number of CRUD operations you perform against the Firestore database. If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/get-collectionreference-count/48540276)** is how you can count the number of documents beneath a collection in Cloud Firestore. As you can see, beside the classic count opertion `+=`, we also have `task.getResult().size()`. I also have mentioned that the best practice to store counters is to store them in Firebase real-time database. So in my opinion, go ahead with that and store them separately.

If you think that your app will grow very fast, another way would be to use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to update the user counter every time you add or delete a users from the your `users` node. This tehnique works very well for big datasets.

And to answer your questions:

> Does getChildrenCount() stores somewhere the latest retrieved number of my users ? Does getChildrenCount() executes each time I run my app to count with += in each child ?

If you are thinking that the latest retrieved number is stored somehow on the disk/memory, no. Everytime you are opening the app, `getChildrenCount()` method will be called to get the latest number of users. If you want to have that number in real-time, then you should attach a listener on `users` reference.