# Firestore Price calculation for overlapping result sets

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I couldn't find any information for this specific scenario: Say I have a these documents in a collection:

```
doc_1
doc_2
doc_3
```

Now, I run two queries. The first query returns `doc_1` and `doc_2`. The second query returns `doc_2` and `doc_3`. So `doc_2` is returned twice in two separate queries. Will Firebase charge me 3 or 4 total reads (-> Will the twice-returned document be counted as one or two reads)?

Answer (score 0):

The number of reads depends of number of documents returned by particular query. In the use case you have 2 queries, both are returning 2 documents so it gives us 4 total reads.

I think this is quite well explained in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing). You can check few other SO questions about it like: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031315/what-counts-as-a-read-operation-in-firestore), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887442/cloud-firestore-how-is-read-calculated) nd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146115/firestore-pricing-does-the-amount-of-documents-in-a-collection-matters) (add I think you can dig more).

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I'm not sure. The documentation which vitooh cites as a source is not entirely clear on what happens if the same document(s) appear(s) in multiple queries: "When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated.". You _could_ read into this that charges are based on individual queries, however the documentation is not quite clear / doesn't go enough into detail IMO.

Comment: @jbxbergdev you can always test it. Just create testing project write a code and run it once. In Firebase console in Firestore you will see reads in "Usage".  Please as well watch the video from the documentation (https://youtu.be/6NegFl9p_sE?t=89) I am not sure what more to add.