# Cloud Firestore limit 8 millions writes per day on single document

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Many realtime apps have documents that act as counters. For example, you might count 'likes' on a post, or the number of visits of a video.

**According to my calculations using cloud firestore this value can not grow more than 8 millions per day**

With Cloud Firestore and Distributed counter I can have (at most) :

```
1 write/second * 100 == 100 writes per second.

1 day = 86.400 seconds

86.400 * 100 = 8.640.000
```

( 100 : Limit maximum depth of subcollections)

How can this limit be exceeded for an application with many users?

Thanks you

Comment: You can also take a look at the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-under-a-collection-in-firestore/48540276#48540276)**.

Answer (score 1):

A proposed solution is explained in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).  You can shard the counter among multiple documents.

Or, you could count with some other storage mechanism (such as Realtime Database) that doesn't have same write limitations as Firestore.

Comment: Hi Doug, is there any downsides for only keeping "counts" in Realtime DB and the rest of our DB in firestore?