# Count unseen messages in group chat with firestore

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I want to track the number of unseen messages for each member of a group chat. I store chat metadata in a `chats` collection, and messages for each chat in `messages/{chatId}`.

I have checked other threads that ask about this, but in this scenario there's a group chat so it's more complicated. The threads that I have read suppose that it's a chat between two people.

I have thought about having a new collection `seenMsgTimestamps` where I store the timestamp of the last message that a certain user has seen for each group chat. In my app, I will listen to changes to `messages` starting from the the timestamp found in `seenMsgTimestamps` for that chat, and count how many new messages are there.

Is this a good approach or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you an go ahead with this solution. Why is this solution good?

> I have thought about having a new collection seenMsgTimestamps where I store the timestamp of the last message that a certain user has seen for each group chat.

You denormalize data by creating a new collection, which is a quite common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases. In your particulasr case, I think is the best solution.

> In my app, I will listen to changes to messages starting from the the timestamp found in seenMsgTimestamps for that chat

That's also good because you are using a query on a limited data set and not on the entire collection, which means less reads, less money to pay but more perfomance.

Regarding the count, I recommend you also read the last part of my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-under-a-collection-in-firestore/48540276#48540276)**. So you can also consider using Firebase realtime database for such conters.

Comment: Regarding the count part though, wouldn't it be ok to just count the number of messages starting from the `seenMsgTimestamp` of that chat in the client side, since I am already listening for changes starting from that timestamp?

Comment: Yes it is but I also showed you an alternative. It's up to you to decide which one you want to use.