# How do you figure out how many documents are created per hour in a Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

What is the best way to figure out how many documents are being created per hour into a Firestore collection. I have created a cloud functions which counts each time a document is added or removed but I can't seem to find a way to figure out the rate at which this is occurring.

Comment: In the last hour or in every hour?

Comment: @AlexMamo I would like to figure out how many documents have been created in the last hour. It should be a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you should add to each document in your collection a new property of type `Date`, that should hold the date and time of its creation. Now you can create a function, in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) that will add to a location in your database the number of documents added in the last hour. You can write this number in a Firebase realtime database rather than in Cloud Firestore, according to the last part of my answer within this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-under-a-collection-in-firestore/48540276#48540276)**.

The function should actually count the number of documents using a query that look like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastHour = date.setDate(today.getDate() - 3600);
db.collection("nameOfCollection").where("date", ">", lastHour);
```

You can trigger this function using [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/) service.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I appreciate your detailed response. I was wondering would it be possible to implement a metadata document for the collection containing the number of posts per hour updated in a similar fashion to this answer for large data sets https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407570/9367155 without having to query the whole database each time and count the snapshot, as with using chron-job this query would be performed every minute.

Comment: Also Excellent answer on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534676/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-under-a-collection-in-firestore/48540276#48540276 out of curiosity when you are talking about limits is sharding free in firebase but costly in firestore?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. Regarding the sharding, if I use Firebase real time database to store the counter instead of firestore would I still have to shard the data as is done here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters or could I just make a counter node that constantly updates. Again thank you for all of your help.

Comment: That solution is used only with Cloud Firestore. There is no need for that in Firebase realtime database.